# Image Ushort array to bitmap format8bppindexed

Tags: c#, arrays, image-processing, bitmap, bitmapimage

I have as input a Ushort array of image data.  Other inputs are gathered here, such as the 'Width, Height'.  The ushort array also carries a Min and Max values, that I want to use, those are stored in 'io_current'.

I want to return a Format8ppIndexed Bitmap, and I have this code but what am I doing wrong?:

```
    private Bitmap CreateBitmap(ushort[,] pixels16)
    {
        int width = pixels16.GetLength(1);
        int height = pixels16.GetLength(0);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        BitmapData bmd = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

        // This 'unsafe' part of the code populates the bitmap bmp with data stored in pixel16.
        // It does so using pointers, and therefore the need for 'unsafe'. 
        unsafe
        {
            //int pixelSize = 4;
            int i, j; //, j1; //, i1;
            byte b;
            ushort sVal;
            double lPixval;
            //The array has max and min constraints
            int distance = io_current.MaximumValue - io_current.MinimumValue;

            for (i = 0; i < bmd.Height; ++i)
            {
                byte* row = (byte*)bmd.Scan0 + (i * bmd.Stride);
                //i1 = i * bmd.Height;

                for (j = 0; j < bmd.Width; ++j)
                {
                    sVal = (ushort)(pixels16[i, j]);

                    lPixval = ((sVal - io_current.MinimumValue) * 255) / distance; // Convert to a 255 value range
                    //lPixval = ((sVal - io_current.MinimumValue) / distance) * 255;
                    //lPixval = 255 - lPixval; //invert the value
                    if (lPixval > 255) lPixval = 255;
                    if (lPixval < 0) lPixval = 0;
                    b = (byte)(lPixval);
                    //j1 = j * pixelSize; //Pixelsize is one
                    row[j] = b; // Just one in 8bpp

                    //Not necessary for format8bppindexed
                    //row[j1] = b; // Red
                    //row[j1 + 1] = b; // Green
                    //row[j1 + 2] = b; // Blue
                    //row[j1 + 3] = 255; //No Alpha channel in 24bit
                }
            }
        }
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);
        return bmp;
    }
```

I'm getting a Black screen, or a one color screen. Basically no usable data is returned.  Obviously from the comments. I tried to convert this from 24bit bitmap code and thought it would be easy.

Comment: 8bppIndex is a pretty useless pixel format, it is expensive to render.  It dates from the early 1990s, back when video adapters were still very primitive and did not have enough RAM.  They used a palette to improve the color fidelity somewhat.  Which is what your forgot.  Just don't bother.

Comment: I'm using Aforge and some of the filters only accept 8bpp format.  See:
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/2c8218cc-921c-34d8-5c88-39c652488490.htm

Comment: In another project: It uses a 24bitmap, and then converts it to 8pp with this line:
result = AForge.Imaging.Filters.Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.BT709.Apply(image);
Then using that 'value' it does the processing.  So I could do that.  But that seems like more time and processing involved.

Comment: Have a look: See the Aforge creator's response to your comments.. I'm not sure this is subjective or what: http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3424&sid=727c8096efdda5bf6476fc6545b9ad94